# How to deal with a problematic 3G dongle

Tags: linux, debian, 3g

I have [an old 3G USB modem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huawei_E220) and I wonder if it's dying because it's very unreliable. Connecting it gives the following (`/var/log/syslog`):

```
Feb 18 22:39:56 thome kernel: [ 5310.999854] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 38 using xhci_hcd
Feb 18 22:39:56 thome mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 38: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2"
Feb 18 22:39:56 thome kernel: [ 5311.017000] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=1003
Feb 18 22:39:56 thome kernel: [ 5311.017004] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Feb 18 22:39:56 thome kernel: [ 5311.017005] usb 1-2: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
Feb 18 22:39:56 thome kernel: [ 5311.017007] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: HUAWEI Technologies
Feb 18 22:39:56 thome mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 38 was not an MTP device
Feb 18 22:39:56 thome kernel: [ 5311.017625] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Feb 18 22:39:56 thome kernel: [ 5311.017976] scsi68 : usb-storage 1-2:1.0
Feb 18 22:39:56 thome kernel: [ 5311.019304] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 38
Feb 18 22:39:56 thome systemd[1]: Starting USB_ModeSwitch...
Feb 18 22:39:56 thome systemd[1]: Started USB_ModeSwitch.
Feb 18 22:39:56 thome udisks-daemon[1319]: **** scsi_host ADDING /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/host68/scsi_host/host68
Feb 18 22:39:56 thome udisks-daemon[1319]: **** scsi_host IGNORING ADD /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/host68/scsi_host/host68
Feb 18 22:39:56 thome udisks-daemon[1319]: **** scsi_host IGNORING REMOVE /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/host68/scsi_host/host68
Feb 18 22:39:56 thome kernel: [ 5311.459645] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 39 using xhci_hcd
Feb 18 22:39:56 thome kernel: [ 5311.476931] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=1003
Feb 18 22:39:56 thome kernel: [ 5311.476934] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Feb 18 22:39:56 thome kernel: [ 5311.476936] usb 1-2: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
Feb 18 22:39:56 thome kernel: [ 5311.476937] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: HUAWEI Technologies
Feb 18 22:39:56 thome kernel: [ 5311.477745] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Feb 18 22:39:56 thome kernel: [ 5311.477918] option 1-2:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Feb 18 22:39:56 thome kernel: [ 5311.477988] usb 1-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
Feb 18 22:39:56 thome kernel: [ 5311.478274] usb-storage 1-2:1.1: USB Mass Storage device detected
Feb 18 22:39:56 thome kernel: [ 5311.478323] option 1-2:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Feb 18 22:39:56 thome kernel: [ 5311.478372] usb 1-2: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
Feb 18 22:39:56 thome kernel: [ 5311.478414] usb-storage 1-2:1.2: USB Mass Storage device detected
Feb 18 22:39:56 thome kernel: [ 5311.478554] scsi71 : usb-storage 1-2:1.2
Feb 18 22:39:56 thome mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 39: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2"
Feb 18 22:39:56 thome mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 39 was not an MTP device
Feb 18 22:39:56 thome systemd[1]: Starting USB_ModeSwitch...
Feb 18 22:39:56 thome udisks-daemon[1319]: **** scsi_host ADDING /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/host71/scsi_host/host71
Feb 18 22:39:56 thome udisks-daemon[1319]: **** scsi_host IGNORING ADD /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/host71/scsi_host/host71
Feb 18 22:39:56 thome systemd[1]: Started USB_ModeSwitch.
Feb 18 22:39:57 thome kernel: [ 5312.476715] scsi 71:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HUAWEI   Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Feb 18 22:39:57 thome kernel: [ 5312.482692] sr0: scsi-1 drive
Feb 18 22:39:57 thome kernel: [ 5312.482844] sr 71:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
Feb 18 22:39:57 thome kernel: [ 5312.482916] sr 71:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
Feb 18 22:39:57 thome kernel: [ 5312.505690] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: WARN Event TRB for slot 28 ep 6 with no TDs queued?
Feb 18 22:39:58 thome udisks-daemon[1319]: **** ADDING /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/host71/target71:0:0/71:0:0:0/block/sr0
Feb 18 22:39:58 thome udisks-daemon[1319]: **** UPDATING /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/host71/target71:0:0/71:0:0:0/block/sr0
Feb 18 22:39:58 thome udisks-daemon[1319]: **** ADDED /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/host71/target71:0:0/71:0:0:0/block/sr0
Feb 18 22:39:58 thome udisks-daemon[1319]: **** EMITTING ADDED for /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/host71/target71:0:0/71:0:0:0/block/sr0
Feb 18 22:39:58 thome kernel: [ 5312.534063] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: WARN Event TRB for slot 28 ep 6 with no TDs queued?
Feb 18 22:39:58 thome udisks-daemon[1319]: **** CHANGING /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/host71/target71:0:0/71:0:0:0/block/sr0
Feb 18 22:39:58 thome udisks-daemon[1319]: **** UPDATING /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/host71/target71:0:0/71:0:0:0/block/sr0
Feb 18 22:39:58 thome udisks-daemon[1319]: **** EMITTING CHANGED for /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/host71/target71:0:0/71:0:0:0/block/sr0
Feb 18 22:39:58 thome udisks-daemon[1319]: **** CHANGED /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/host71/target71:0:0/71:0:0:0/block/sr0
Feb 18 22:39:58 thome org.gtk.Private.UDisks2VolumeMonitor[1200]: ### debug: emit_signal: 0x1cf01b0
Feb 18 22:40:02 thome kernel: [ 5316.956198] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: WARN Event TRB for slot 28 ep 6 with no TDs queued?
Feb 18 22:40:02 thome udisks-daemon[1319]: **** CHANGING /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/host71/target71:0:0/71:0:0:0/block/sr0
Feb 18 22:40:02 thome udisks-daemon[1319]: **** UPDATING /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/host71/target71:0:0/71:0:0:0/block/sr0
Feb 18 22:40:02 thome udisks-daemon[1319]: **** EMITTING CHANGED for /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/host71/target71:0:0/71:0:0:0/block/sr0
Feb 18 22:40:02 thome udisks-daemon[1319]: **** CHANGED /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/host71/target71:0:0/71:0:0:0/block/sr0
Feb 18 22:40:02 thome org.gtk.Private.UDisks2VolumeMonitor[1200]: ### debug: emit_signal: 0x1cf01b0
```

It does not work (i.e. it is not available via **nm-applet** so that I can connect to the internet). I have seen this issue on two separate Debian machines. The one reliable workaround for this problem is rebooting the machine :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That log looks like the effect I get from pulling out a USB drive without unmounting and reinserting. Doing that also remounts the USB on new device number.

Your 3G modem probably has a build in storage (for the (windows) driver), so if this happens without you taking the the modem out, it could indicate bad contacts on the USB connector or an almost broken connection within the modem.

I would try to clean the connectors with a Q-tip (flattened if possible if it has hollow plastic tube), with a very tiny amount of alcohol.

If something is (almost) broken within the modem, there is probably little you can do. I have not seen any that you would not have to break open, because non of them did have accessible screws. I did break a HUAWEI modem open and it would not reassemble, and I could not get any meaningful soldering done on the tiny board inside.